# How does this contract scam work?

Tags: solidity, scam

Noticed this wierd contract someone keeps creating, looks like some sort of scam, how does it work?

https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fa738cf30036505d106b22f60e64bf52e64aa77/advanced#code:

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2020-08-16
*/

contract a1_quiz
{
    function Try(string _response) external payable 
    {
        require(msg.sender == tx.origin);

        if(responseHash == keccak256(_response) && msg.value > 1 ether)
        {
            msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
        }
    }

    string public question;

    bytes32 responseHash;

    mapping (bytes32=>bool) admin;

    function Start(string _question, string _response) public payable isAdmin{
        if(responseHash==0x0){
            responseHash = keccak256(_response);
            question = _question;
        }
    }

    function Stop() public payable isAdmin {
        msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    function New(string _question, bytes32 _responseHash) public payable isAdmin {
        question = _question;
        responseHash = _responseHash;
    }

    constructor(bytes32[] admins) public{
        for(uint256 i=0; i< admins.length; i++){
            admin[admins[i]] = true;        
        }       
    }

    modifier isAdmin(){
        require(admin[keccak256(msg.sender)]);
        _;
    }

    function() public payable{}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only read the contract regular transaction history you would assume that after creation it was initialized by calling `Start(string _question, string _response)` at transaction [`0xc96ddea6...`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc96ddea66b1419abd2fe19d022d281a22a50dfecc105c7e2d63aee4bfce344ed) block 10668934 with

- _question = "What kind of clothes do lawyers wear?"
- _response = " LawsuiT "

But if you see the internal transactions there was a previous call to `function New(string _question, bytes32 _responseHash)` in transaction [0xbed05f75...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbed05f75bf315592316b4217408d4cad0af863549c477aa64da7ca536b5b3c38/advanced) at block 10668933.

The call to `Start` did not change `responseHash` as a victim would have expected, so the call to `Try` will fail.

Note: Don't play with these "honey pots", it is very easy to lose and unlikely you will win.